# Need to reg add in commandline the 2 entries in red

Tags: windows-registry

Can´t boot windows 10
But can open a command line
Need to add command line the 2 entries in red in attached picture
But not sure about the syntax

[image]

Comment: `reg add <keyname> [{/v valuename | /ve}] [/t datatype] [/s separator] [/d data] [/f]` from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-add

Comment: N.B.: The Registry is stored in different files. If you cannot boot, parts of it might be inaccessible. Likely, you *can* get to HKLM, but it's possible you might also make the Registry unusable, requiring reinstallation of Windows... which might also fix the issue.